# The meaning of “the inconsistencies are generally consistent”

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

I was watching a TV program and I couldn’t quite get the meaning of a phrase.

> The doughnuts don’t look that great
>
> I know there are inconsistencies but **the inconsistencies are generally
>   consistent**

What does that phrase mean?

Comment: Ah, [the Apprentice...](https://youtu.be/uhW2aqumncY?t=6s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase means that if there is something missing on some doughnuts it is missing on most/ all of them.

For example if the icing isn’t put on properly on some doughnuts like it’s meant to be, it isn’t put on properly for most of them.